# How to pass javascript data to controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult GetFilterUsers(int pageNumber)
{

    //......

}
```

This is my js code:

```
$('#users-data-table').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "@(Url.Action("GetFilterUsers", "Users", new { area = "Admin" }))/" + table.page.info().page, 
                type: "GET"
            }
        });
```

this string is now working

```
url: "@(Url.Action("GetFilterUsers", "Users", new { area = "Admin" }))/" + table.page.info().page,
```

How can I pass `table.page.info().page` into my controller?

Comment: remove type part from ajax and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the url to

```
url: '@(Url.Action("GetFilterUsers", "Users", new { area = "Admin" }))?pageNumber=' + table.page.info()
```

Now url will pass pageNumber in query string.
If you want to pass the url as `url: "@(Url.Action("GetFilterUsers", "Users", new { area = "Admin" }))/" + table.page.info().page` then you should define and register the route and action route.